# Double integral with nested heaviside function

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, step-function

I encounter the following form of integrals and I would like some suggestions on how I can solve it analytically (numerically is straightforward):

$$ F(a,b,c) = \int_{0}^\beta  \int_{0}^\beta \int_{0}^\beta e^{ta+t_1 b + t_2 c}~\theta(t>t_1>t_2>0)\,dt_2\, dt_1\,dt,$$

where $a,b,c,$ are just some numerical values (treat them as irrelevant constants).

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Can you please clarify what you mean by $\theta(t>t_1>t_2>0)?$

Comment: @AdrianKeister I think it's some function of 3 variables that's equal to $1$ when $t > t_1 > t_2 > 0$ and $0$ otherwise

Comment: @Dylan: So maybe $\theta(t-t_1)\,\theta(t_1-t_2)\,\theta(t_2)?$

Comment: @Adrian: I think that it's valid to assume this product form

Comment: In that case, I believe it's sufficient to make the limits $$ \int_{t_2=0}^{t_2=\beta} \int_{t_1=t_2}^{t_1=\beta} \int_{t=t_1}^{t=\beta} f(t,t_1,t_2)\ dt\ dt_1\ dt_2 $$ and integrate directly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The integral separates out, via Dylan's suggestion, into the following:
\begin{align*}F(a,b,c) &= \int_{0}^\beta  \int_{t_2}^\beta \int_{t_1}^\beta e^{ta+t_1 b + t_2 c}\,dt\, dt_1\,dt_2 \\
&=\int_0^{\beta}e^{ct_2}\int_{t_2}^{\beta}e^{bt_1}\int_{t_1}^{\beta}e^{at}\,dt\,dt_1\,dt_2 \\
&=\int_0^{\beta}e^{ct_2}\int_{t_2}^{\beta}e^{bt_1}\left(\frac{e^{at}}{a}\right)\Bigg|_{t_1}^{\beta}\,dt_1\,dt_2 \\
&=\int_0^{\beta}e^{ct_2}\int_{t_2}^{\beta}e^{bt_1}\left(\frac{e^{a\beta}-e^{at_1}}{a}\right)\,dt_1\,dt_2 \\
&=\int_0^{\beta}e^{ct_2}\int_{t_2}^{\beta}\left(\frac{e^{a\beta+bt_1}-e^{(a+b)t_1}}{a}\right)\,dt_1\,dt_2.
\end{align*}
Surely you can finish? It's a bit tedious, but quite straight-forward.

Comment: Sure!! Thanks for your answer guys! I did this trick with the product notation of the theta function. Hope that its correct after all!